# pdf - allowing running footer within a break-inside html table

Tags: html, css, pdf, footer, weasyprint

I'm using weasyprint to generate pdf server-side. The page looks like this:

[image]

With main html sections being:

```
<body id="page-top">
    <div id="header" class="avoidInside">
    </div>
    <table class="details_body">
    </table>
    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
```

With relevant css:

```
.avoidInside {
    break-inside: avoid;
}
table {
    break-inside: auto;
}
tr {
    break-after: auto;
}
```

So the top section with addresses & generic info if the div#header, then I have a table section which can be arbitrarily large. Each page should have a footer (e.g. the taxes & signature section).

The footer works this way (rendering from django templates):

```
    <div class="avoidInside">
        {% include header|default:"projectlibs/pdf_outputs/header.html" %}
        {% include content_body|default:"projectlibs/pdf_outputs/content_body.html"  %}
    </div>
    {% include footer|default:"projectlibs/pdf_outputs/footer.html"  %}
    <div class="break"> this should break</div>
    {% include extras|default:"projectlibs/pdf_outputs/extras.html"  %}
```

With the relevant css:

```
@page {
    size: letter;
    /* need to reserve a margin (50mm) for the footer*/
    margin: 5mm 0mm 50mm 0mm;
    padding: 0mm 5mm 0mm 5mm;
    /*manages the running footer at the end of all pages*/
    @bottom-left {
        content: element(footer);
    }
}
/* manages NOT displaying the running footer in the last page*/
@page break {
    size: letter;
    margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;
    padding: 5mm 5mm 0mm 5mm;
}
footer {
    position: running(footer);
    width: 205mm;
}
```

If I need to break the main table, then the footer only appears after the complete table:
[image]

I think this is due to the fact that the footer is set to display @bottom-left of @page, and I am guessing the the "page" within the broken table isn't considered a page, or perhaps needs to be addressed with a different selector? How?

Answer (score 0):

Answer was suggested by liZe (Guillaume Ayoub) [over at the chat](https://matrix.to/#/#CourtBouillon_WeasyPrint:gitter.im).

But basically, putting the footer above the table content within which the footer needs to be placed does the trick. The Django template becomes:

```
<body id="page-top">
        <div class="avoidInside">
            {% include header|default:"projectlibs/pdf_outputs/header/header.html" %}
            {% include footer|default:"projectlibs/pdf_outputs/footer/footer.html" %}
            {% include content_body|default:"projectlibs/pdf_outputs/content_body/content_body.html" %}
        </div>
        <div class="break"></div>
        {% include extras|default:"projectlibs/pdf_outputs/extras/legal_prints.html" %}
</body>
```

Guessing it has to do with the order in which things are parsed. The footer might need to have been parsed already, if it is to be placed in the content_body html table. Perhaps otherwise the parser then attempts to place the running footer within the table in the 1st margin above (see image), but since the footer hasn't been parsed at that point, just an empty string is placed (or there's an internal error, but anyways nothing happens). If one puts the footer before however, it has been parsed, it exists and is placed correctly.